# How to pass list of objects from spring mvc to jquery using ajax and json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

can anyone please suggest me, how to pass and display List of objects from SpringMVC to jsp page to jquery using AJAX, JQuery , JSON.

**Here is my controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ViewUserList", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<WizardTO> retriveUserList(@RequestParam(value = "Role") String Role) {
        WizardDAO dao = new WizardDAO();
        List<WizardTO> userList= dao.getUserList(Role);
        return userList;
        /*String str="returned from controller";
        return str;*/   // its working
    }
```

**And Here is my jquery code (inside jsp file for request and response handling )**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script >  
    function doajax(){
        alert("in doajax");
       // jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        $.ajax({    
            url: '\ViewUserList',
            type: 'get',
            data: "Role="+ $("#MyRole").val(),
            dataType: "json",
           /*   success:function(list){
                alert("success" +list);
            } , */
             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 alert("success " +data +textStatus+jqXHR);
                 console.log(data.error);
                },
         //   error : alert("Error"),
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error "+"jqXHR "+jqXHR+" textStatus "+textStatus+" errorThrown "+errorThrown);
             console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }   
/*          colNames:['UserID','FirstName', 'LastName', 'Role'], 
            colModel:[ 
                       {name:'UserID',index:'UserID', width:55}, 
                       {name:'FirstName',index:'FirstName', width:100}, 
                       {name:'LastName',index:'LastName', width:100}, 
                       {name:'Role',index:'Role', width:100}, 
                      ], 
                // rowNum:10, 
                 //rowList:[10,20,30], 
                 pager: '#UserListDiv', 
                 sortname: 'id', 
                 viewrecords: true, 
                 sortorder: "desc", 
                 caption:"Releted User List", 
                 editurl:"" 
                }).navGrid("#UserListDiv",
                        {edit:false,add:false,del:false});  */
        });
    }
</script>
```

this doajax() method is called when i click on particular href link,i also tried to use jquery grid to display received object, but i am doing some mistakes,

I am new in springmvc and jquery;i just started working with spring-mvc jquery and ajax before some days.

i want to print table in particular division, i tried to return string from controller to jquery and it worked but i dont know how to return list of array from controller to jquery.

Can anyone please help me to for that issue...??
(and i don't want to load other JSP page, i want to load data on same page from where i am sending request, in short i want to do that with help of ajax,json and jquery).

Comment: `url: '\ViewUserList',` should be `url: '/ViewUserList',` also not able to see `@controller` annotation anywhere. Do you have this on top of your controller??

Comment: hello jai thank you for the response..., yes i already defined '@controller' at top and also 'url is /ViewUserList' at both place in program, just i did some copy paste mistake in here. and this program is running for passing string and catching string by jquery. just i dont know how to pass list of object and how to display objects data in table in jsp page using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

#### There are two things which i noticed and i commented it though:

1. your ajax's `url : "\ViewUserList"` is not using correct slash `\`.
2. you have not posted the controller's annotation `@Controller`

so you can add these two and see if this helps:

### Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/ViewUserList", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

### jquery ajax:

change this:

```
url: '\ViewUserList',
```

to this:

```
url: '/ViewUserList',
```

Check to see if this sorts it out.